# Alamofire Skipping Requests

Tags: swift, alamofire

I used the following code to send an HTTP GET request

`let request = AF.request("https://swapi.dev/api/films/?format=json") request.responseJSON { (data) in print(data) }`

The code never reach to print(data), actually the request never been even sent. I read through all tutorial online and I did not see any problem running this code.

I was expecting to receive the JSON information and to issue a request to the server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No Error message? What's do you see in the debugger?

Comment: What call that code? Is the object deallocated too soon?